# Discord.js bot that is hosted with Heroku is offline

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I am making a discord chatbot and I host it in Heroku, except it is offline. Here are my logs:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.17.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.13
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       added 15 packages in 0.775s
       
-----> Build
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       audited 15 packages in 0.458s
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> worker
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 33.1M
-----> Launching...
       Released v7
       https://dahelperjs.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

What's bugging me is that it says "Default types for buildpack: web" except the tutorial that I followed said that I needed worker-type buildpacks because the web one is only for web applications and is insufficient in this case.
How do I change this?

Comment: If you are using heroku's free plan you can only have so many hours of hosting a month. Have you checked to make sure that you actually have hours left?

Comment: @Tyler2P Yes I do. Weird